# ignore .git .gitignore from svn and .svnignore .svn from git

Tags: git, svn, gitignore, svnignore

**Background :**

To ignore `.svn` and `.svnignore` using `.gitignore` there is no problem.
But to do so in the inverse I didn't achieve that.

**What I have tried :**

```
svn propset svn:ignore -R -F .svnignore .
```

**.svnignore**

```
*~
*.sw[mnpcod]
*.log
*.tmp
*.tmp.*
log.txt
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace

.idea/
.vscode/
.sass-cache/
.versions/
coverage/
dist/
node_modules/
tmp/
temp/
$RECYCLE.BIN/

.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

.package.tmp.json

src/themes/version.scss
scripts/e2e/webpackEntryPoints.json
scripts/build/e2e-generated-tsconfig.json
*.css.ts

# demo stuff
demos/node_modules
demos/polyfills
demos/css
demos/fonts
demos/src/**/*.js*
demos/src/**/*.ngfactory.ts
demos/src/**/*.d.ts
demos/src/**/*.metadata.json

node_modules/
platforms/

# Git files
.git
.gitignore
```

**Result**

Every file/directory become under version except .git

```
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.idea'
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.idea/copyright'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'hooks'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'hooks/after_platform_add'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'hooks/after_plugin_add'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'hooks/after_plugin_rm'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'hooks/after_prepare'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'hooks/before_platform_add'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/.bin'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/abbrev'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/sparkles'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/spdx-correct'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/spdx-expression-parse'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/spdx-license-ids'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/sshpk'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/sshpk/bin'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/sshpk/lib'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/sshpk/lib/formats'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/sshpk/man'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/sshpk/man/man1'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/sshpk/node_modules'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/sshpk/node_modules/assert-plus'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/stream-consume'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/stream-consume/test'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/string-width'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/string_decoder'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/stringstream'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/strip-ansi'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/strip-bom'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/strip-indent'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/supports-color'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/tar'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/tar/examples'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/tar/lib'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/tar/test'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/through2'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/user-home'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl/lib'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl/test'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/dest'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/dest/writeContents'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/lib/src/getContents'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/.bin'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/clone'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/test'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/strip-bom'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/vinyl'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/xtend'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/y18n'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/yallist'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/yallist/test'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'node_modules/yargs'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc/de'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc/es'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc/fr'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc/it'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc/ja'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc/ko'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc/pl'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc/ru'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/doc/zh'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/blackberry10'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/blackberry10/native'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/blackberry10/native/device'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/blackberry10/native/public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/blackberry10/native/public/json'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/blackberry10/native/simulator'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/blackberry10/native/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/browser'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/firefoxos'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/tizen'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/ubuntu'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/windows'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/windows/GlobalizationProxy'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/windows/GlobalizationProxy/GlobalizationProxy'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/windows/GlobalizationProxy/GlobalizationProxy/Cordova'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/windows/GlobalizationProxy/GlobalizationProxy/Cordova/JSON'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/windows/GlobalizationProxy/GlobalizationProxy/Globalization'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/windows/GlobalizationProxy/GlobalizationProxy/Properties'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/src/wp'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/tests'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/www'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/www/browser'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/www/firefoxos'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/www/firefoxos/locales'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-globalization/www/ubuntu'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc/de'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc/es'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc/fr'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc/it'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc/ja'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc/ko'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc/pl'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc/ru'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/doc/zh'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/blackberry10'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/browser'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/tizen'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/ubuntu'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/wp'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest/CDVSplashScreenLibTests'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest/CDVSplashScreenTest.xcodeproj'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest/CDVSplashScreenTest.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest/CDVSplashScreenTest.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest/CDVSplashScreenTest.xcodeproj/xcshareddata'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest/CDVSplashScreenTest.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest.xcworkspace'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest.xcworkspace/xcshareddata'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/CDVSplashScreenTest.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/xcschemes'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/doc'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/doc/de'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/doc/es'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/doc/fr'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/doc/it'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/doc/ja'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/doc/ko'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/doc/pl'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tests/ios/doc/zh'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/windows'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc/de'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc/es'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc/fr'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc/it'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc/ja'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc/ko'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc/pl'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc/ru'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/doc/zh'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/src/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/src/browser'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/src/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/src/windows'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/src/wp'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/tests'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/www'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/doc'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/doc/de'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/doc/es'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/doc/fr'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/doc/it'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/doc/ja'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/doc/ko'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/doc/pl'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/doc/zh'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/src/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/screenshots'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/android/nl'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/android/nl/xservices'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/android/nl/xservices/plugins'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native/device'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native/device/public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native/device/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native/public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native/public/json'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native/simulator'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native/simulator/public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native/simulator/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/blackberry10/native/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/src/wp8'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/test'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/cordova-plugin-x-toast/www'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/src/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/src/android/notification'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/src/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/src/windows'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/www'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native/device'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native/device/public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native/device/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native/public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native/public/json'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native/simulator'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native/simulator/public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native/simulator/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/blackberry10/native/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/src/windows'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/browser'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/docs'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/example'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/example/server'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/hooks'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/hooks/windows'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/spec'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/spec/helper'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/android/com'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/android/com/adobe'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/android/com/adobe/phonegap'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/android/com/adobe/phonegap/push'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/browser'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GGLInstanceID'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GGLInstanceID/Headers'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GGLInstanceID/Headers/Public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GGLInstanceID/Libraries'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/Google'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/Google/Headers'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/Google/Headers/GGLCloudMessaging'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/Google/Headers/GGLCloudMessaging/Public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/Google/Headers/GGLCore'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/Google/Headers/GGLCore/Public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/Google/Headers/ModuleHeaders'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/Google/Libraries'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleCloudMessaging'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleCloudMessaging/Headers/Public'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleIPhoneUtilities'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleIPhoneUtilities/Libraries'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleInterchangeUtilities'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Libraries'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleNetworkingUtilities'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleSymbolUtilities'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleUtilities'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/ios/GoogleUtilities/Libraries'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/src/windows'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/www'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/www/browser'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'resources'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'resources/android'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'resources/android/icon'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'resources/android/splash'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'resources/ios'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'resources/ios/icon'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'resources/ios/splash'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'rest'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'scss'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/XXX'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/XX/YY'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/XXXX'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/XXX/YY'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/BB'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/home'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/WWW'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/WWW/YY'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/login'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/login/searchLogin'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/model'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/model/local'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/profil'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/push'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/services'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/services/dataJson'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/services/rest'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/app/start'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/css'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/dataJson'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/img'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/js'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/js/services'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/js/services/img'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular-animate'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular-resource'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular-sanitize'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular-translate'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular-translate-loader-static-files'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular-ui-router'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular-ui-router/api'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular-ui-router/release'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/angular-ui-router/src'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ionic'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ionic/css'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ionic/fonts'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ionic/js'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ionic/js/angular'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ionic/js/angular-ui'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ionic/scss'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ionic/scss/ionicons'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ngCordova'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/lib/ngCordova/dist'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/login'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/login/searchLogin'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/templates'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'www/translations'
```